# How can I mock StorageAccessFramework from expo-file-system using Jest

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo

I am importing as per the docs as follows:

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
const { StorageAccessFramework } = FileSystem;
```

On a user request the following code is executed:

```
const permissions = await StorageAccessFramework.requestDirectoryPermissionsAsync();
  if (permissions.granted) {
     // Selected folder from device
  }
```

This works fine in practice. The user grants perission and a folder is selected. But how can I mock `StorageAccessFramework` in my tests?